# Full equations for assymetrical stripline

Tags: impedance, capacitance

Are there any good sources for nonlimited equations of an asymmetrical stripline impedance. I would like to calculate capacitance, but I cannot get valid results out of the commonly used calculators and published results as the W/H ratio is outside of where the results are anywhere close to accurate.

Comment: I expect there are.

Comment: search for field solvers, and enter your geometry in one, works for arbitrary shapes.